# AMPscript to count all rows

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I would like to count all rows in a Data Extension in Marketing Cloud.

The only way I have seen is using LookupRows which has a max of 2000 rows.

I just want to know how many rows, there is no need for any of the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to count all DE rows with AMPscript use [DataExtensionRowCount()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/dataextensionrowcount.htm) function